# Header function asks the user for the file to be opened rather than automatically?

Tags: php

I am trying to redirect the user to simply another phtml file when they logout. I am using the function header like so:

```
header('Location: ../../Site/index.phtml');
exit;
```

In reality when that runs, the user is greeted if they want the file to be opened and they're not automatically re-directed. Like shown in the image. How can I get them to redirected please without the dialog (automatically). I am running a localhost.
Many thanks

[Image of the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/twdV1.png)

Comment: 1) are you 100% sure nothing is output before coming there? 2) use an absolute URL not a relative one 3) what does happen when you try to enter directly the URL in your browser? Same symptoms or not? If same, it means the problem is not in your PHP but just that this page is not served probably with the appropriate `Content-Type: text/html` header.

Comment: Thank you it's fixed now. Sorry again for the stupidity, it's those tiny mistakes. I used an absolute URL for anyone having this issue and it works. Thank you again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is likely due to the fact that `.phtml` is a **very** old PHP file extension (from PHP 2, circa 1997). We're now on PHP 7, and as such, most web servers don't even have logic built in to handle the `.phtml` extension.

Because your webserver (in this case `localhost`) doesn't know what to do with the file, it falls back and lets your browser handle it. Because your browser doesn't have an associated default file handler for the extension, it prompts you for an action (assuming a user would be more familiar with a file extension).

The **easiest** way to resolve this would be to simply switch to the `.php` extension, as I'm yet to encounter a server that is unable to handle the main PHP extension.

If you are still having issues opening the file, ensure that you specify the type of the file with `header("Content-Type: text/html")`, which is the default for PHP. This shouldn't be necessary, but will ensure that your browser correctly parses the file as a PHP file.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: You're correct because when I changed it to .php, it worked correctly. But why would they provide the functionality of .phtml on phpstorm if it is very old? What can you replace .phtml with?